# Есть ли возможность узнать информацию о ветке master, находясь на любой ветке?

Tags: git

Мне нужно узнать tag ветки master независимо от того, на какой ветке я нахожусь

Comment: Что такое `tag ветки master`? Как вы его узнаете, если вы находитесь на ветке `master`?

Comment: хэш коммита мб?

Comment: К каждому коммиту можно проставить тэг, допустим предпоследнему(или последнему) коммиту ветки master был добавлен тэг "2.1" - его мне и нужно получить.

Comment: `$ git show 2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git describe --tags  master`

вернет последний тег на ветке `master` независимо от текущей ветки.